# Storing UDID in a database server - Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, ajax

I have generated a UDID string on the client side of Android. I need to send this to the javascript side so that it could communicate to the database server (via php) in order to store this UDID.

Is there a way to do it either directly (by avoiding php) or otherwise?

** My Android application has a WebView

Comment: can't you pass it as an http param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post to http with params:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/yourexample.php");



try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UDID", "12345"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

for your server side maybe it would be useful to learn somethings about web api's. take a look at this 2 links to start from some place:
[Creating a RESTful API with PHP](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/)
[[GUIDE] Android Client-Server Communication (PHP-MYSQL REST API)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2325799)

You should show what you have already done, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to make better - to the point- questions

Comment: Thanks. But how do I call this in php. $_POST?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data in a database from an Android app, without having to learn a server-side language, the simplest soulution is to use a MBaaS (Mobile Backend as a service) like :

- [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)
- [Appback](https://appback.com/)

If you want to have lower fees you could also host your own solution but this could get more complicated:

- http://hood.ie/
- http://firehose.io/
- http://remotestorage.io/
- http://socky.org/
- http://sockethub.org/
- http://deployd.com/

My personal preference is Hoodie.

You could also generate your own RESTful API using Node.js + Express with MongoDB :

[Yeoman generator for RESTful API](https://github.com/brianviveiros/generator-rest-express)